# I need to get a list of variables in a javascript method when using graalvm.polyglot, but I get an empty collection

Tags: javascript, graalvm

This is my code

```java
package com.fbi.fvite;

import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.management.ExecutionListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {
    private static Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("polyglot.engine.WarnInterpreterOnly", "false");

        // Enable CommonJS experimental support.
        options.put("js.commonjs-require", "true");
        options.put("js.esm-eval-returns-exports", "true");
        options.put("js.commonjs-require-cwd", "projects/" + CommAttr.projectId + "/src/modules");


        Source js = null;
        try {
            js = Source.newBuilder("js","""
                    export default {
                                        
                        /**
                         * test method
                         */
                        test(params) {\s
                            const { hello, world } = params;
                            var aaa = '123';
                                        
                            return {
                                hello,
                                world
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    """,
                    "test.mjs"
            ).mimeType("application/javascript+module").build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        try(Context context = Context.newBuilder()
                .allowAllAccess(true)
                .options(options)
                .allowExperimentalOptions(true)
                .allowIO(true)
                .build()){
            Value fun = context.eval(js).getMember("default").getMember("test");

            ExecutionListener listener = ExecutionListener.newBuilder()
                    .onEnter((e) -> {
                        // TODO Here I want to get list of variables in "test" method, But what I get is an empty collection。
                        Set<String> source = fun.getMemberKeys();
                        Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();
                        for (String s : source) {
                            variables.put(s, fun.getMember(s));
                        }

                        SourceSection section = e.getLocation();
                        System.out.println("line: " + section.getStartLine() + ", code: " + section.getCharacters() + ", variables: " + variables);
                    })
                    .statements(true)
                    .collectInputValues(true)
                    .attach(context.getEngine());
            Value value = fun.execute(Map.of("hello", "world"));
            System.out.println("完毕，返回值：" + value);
            listener.close();
        }
    }

}
```

I need to get the variable list of the current stack in `ExecutionListener.onEnter`, but all I get is empty and I don't know how to fix it

I don't have any solution ideas, I hope to get the list of variables in the method, but in fact I can only get the members in "export default" at most, and I can't get further variables in the “test”